# Versioning Gradle native plugin builds

Tags: java, c, gradle, versioning

Here's my first attempt at a C program built with [Gradle's C plugin](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/nativeBinaries.html):

```
apply plugin: 'c'

model {
    components {
        derpus(NativeExecutableSpec) {
            sources {
                c(CSourceSet) {
                    source {
                        srcDir "src/derpus/c"
                        include "**/*.c"
                    }
                    exportedHeaders {
                        srcDir "src/derpus/headers"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This produces an executable called `derpus.exe`. I would like, if at all possible, to **version** these executables (`derpus-1.0.0.exe`, `derpus-1.0.1.exe`, etc.). When I change the `derpus` closure to `derpus-1.0.0` like so:

> derpus-1.0.0(NativeExecutableSpec) {

And run `gradle clean build` I get:

```
D:\workspace\derp\20150505\derpus>gradlew clean build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\derpus\build.gradle' line: 6

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'D:\derpus\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
    build file 'D:\derpus\build.gradle': 6: unexpected tok
    en: 0 @ line 6, column 20.
                    derpus-1.0.0(NativeExecutableSpec) {
                               ^

    1 error
```

Does anybody know of a way to version these executables?

---

#### Update

Now this is **really** weird! Taking Amnon's advice, I added a `gradle.properties` file that defined `version=1.0.0`. I then modified my `model` closure to:

```
model {
    components {
        derpus(NativeExecutableSpec) {
            sources {
                c(CSourceSet) {
                    source {
                        srcDir "src/derpus/c"
                        include "**/*.c"
                    }
                    exportedHeaders {
                        srcDir "src/derpus/headers"
                    }
                }
            }

            baseName = "derpus-${version}"
        }
    }
}
```

This produces an executable named `derpus-1` (what?!?!)!

So then I modified `model` again:

```
version = "3.4"

model {
    components {
        derpus(NativeExecutableSpec) {
            sources {
                c(CSourceSet) {
                    source {
                        srcDir "src/derpus/c"
                        include "**/*.c"
                    }
                    exportedHeaders {
                        srcDir "src/derpus/headers"
                    }
                }
            }

            baseName = "derpus-${version}"
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, this should *overrdide* the version set in `gradle.properties`, however after running `gradle clean build`, it produces `derpus-3`!

So I modified `model` yet again:

```
model {
    components {
        derpus(NativeExecutableSpec) {
            sources {
                c(CSourceSet) {
                    source {
                        srcDir "src/derpus/c"
                        include "**/*.c"
                    }
                    exportedHeaders {
                        srcDir "src/derpus/headers"
                    }
                }
            }

            baseName = "derpus-3.4.5"
        }
    }
}
```

This produces `derpus-3.4`!!! **What is going on here?!?** Does the C plugin have a bug in it that doesn't honor the full `version` variable?

Answer (score 1):

In your example above the problem with `derpus-1.0.0` is the gradle things that the dash character is a minus which is unexpected in a component spec name, thus the failure. You can overcome this by wrapping `derpus-1.0.0` with inverted commas. A better approach, however, would be to apply the version to the `baseName` property of the component spec, i.e. add the following line under `derpus` component definition:

```
baseName = "derpus-1.0.0"
```

or

```
baseName = "derpus-$version"
```

Where in the second case the version property [`$version`](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:version) is taken from the `project` object.

**Update**

Per [smeeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4009451/smeeb) comments below another workaround that can be applied is to directly rename the target binaries:

```
afterEvaluate {
    RenameNativeBinaries()
}

def RenameNativeBinaries() {
    binaries.all { b ->
        if (b instanceof SharedLibraryBinarySpec) {
            b.sharedLibraryFile = ReconstructFileName(b.sharedLibraryFile)
        } else if (b instanceof StaticLibraryBinarySpec) {
            b.staticLibraryFile = ReconstructFileName(b.staticLibraryFile)
        } 
    }
}

def ReconstructFileName(File originalFile) {
    def originalFileName = originalFile.absolutePath
    def filePath = FilenameUtils.getFullPath(originalFileName)
    def baseName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(originalFileName)
    def extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(originalFileName)

    def newName = "$baseName-$version.$extension"
    def newFile = new File(filePath, newName)
    newFile
}
```

Where `FilenameUtils` is taken from `commons-io`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Amnon Shochot (+1) - however please see my update. It seems the C plugin is truncating `$version` (removing trailing `0`'s and/or patch numbers). Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: I think this is a definite bug - if I change `version` in `gradle.properties` to `4.0.8.0` it produces `derpus-4.0.8.exe`. Who can I report this to?

Comment: [Reported](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/native-c-plugin-doesnt-honor-versions/9593)